# Arduino Data to Cloud without shield []

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, datalogging

I am performing basic analogue read like temperature and LDR, reading the data serially, but I would like to deploy it online to cloud platforms like (Plotly, Xively, ThingSpeak, or DataSparkFun). Is that feasible? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a shield? Yes, it's possible.

You send it serially to your computer as you are doing now. Then you write some software for your computer to read that data serially and send it on to your chosen web service.

Can the Arduino magically send data to the internet by itself without you investing in a network connection of some form (WiFi shield, Ethernet Shield, etc)? No, of course not. If it could there would be no market for the network shields, and so they wouldn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @Majenko, any recommended software to deploy the data online? like Python, Node.JS? C#..

Comment: @BadreddineZebbiche Whatever you feel most comfortable programming in.

Comment: Would it be okay to provide any links? I am more into hardware. Not familiar with both..

Comment: Links to what? Just choose a language already. I can't tell you what you are best at programming in. Just pick one and try it. If you don't like it, try another. If you're on Windows you're probably best off using one that is included with something like Visual Studio since that makes it "simple" to program. Personally I program mostly in C or C++ on Linux, but that takes more experience than programming in, say, Python (which I loathe, but some beginners really love).